# Using Keychain to store username after login xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to store username and password using Keychain (in order to access that data later in my ProfileViewController) and I'm a little bit lost because it's my first time using Keychain and the Apple documentation is so big and confusing and I can't find a good example or tutorial to follow with a simple username and password stored and read from another ViewController.

Can you help me with that? Can you show me some example or a good tutorial to learn and follow that?

I have already imported the security framework, but now I don't know which file I have to add to my project to go on with the Keychain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check https://github.com/lukef/IXKeychain & https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend this wrapper for the Keychain, [SSKeychain](https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain). Once you have that added to your project, all you need to call in your code is:

Get a password:

```
NSString *usersPassword = [SSKeychain passwordForService:@"login" account:@"account"];
```

Set a password:

```
NSString *enteredPassword = self.passworldField.text;
[SSKeychain setPassword:enteredPassword forService:@"login" account:@"account"];
```

Comment: Thanks @Acey. There is more documentation about that? Because I get an error with serviceName and I would like to know how i have to declare that in order to work.

Comment: You can use whatever string you want for serviceName, "login" might be a good value. Just remember to use the same value when fetching the password and setting it. For 'account' use the users login account, and password, well the password =)

Comment: Thanks again @Acey. What I have to do when I have this error? Use of undeclared identifier 'password' ? I have just added that line: [SSKeychain setPassword:(NSString *)password forService:(NSString *)serviceName account:(NSString *)account].

Comment: You need to put in actual variables in place of what I wrote. Editing my post to make it more clear.

Comment: ok, si I changed "password" for my variable name. But now I get another error: Use of undeclared identifier 'serviceName' ? How I have to declare that "serviceName"? Much appreciated @Acey

Comment: Thanks mate I will find more documentation because I want to learn whats exactly "forService" and "account". Much appreciated again @Acey :) you help me a lot with that.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can try to use [UICKeyChainStore](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/UICKeyChainStore) which let you use KeyChain in a much simpler way.